# Google Tag Manager custom event listener not working

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, data-layers, google-datalayer

I'm creating a event listener in the Google Tag manager, that should listen to any keypress. I followed [this guide](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/custom-event-listeners-gtm/#comment-818535).

Here is my change listener:

```
<script>
  var eventType = "keydown"; 
  if (document.addEventListener) { 
    document.addEventListener(eventType, {{generic event handler}}, false); 
  } else if (document.attachEvent) { 
    document.attachEvent('on' + eventType, {{generic event handler}}); 
  }
</script>
```

I included the fields and tags as in the blog. Now I couldnt find the Document Path in the Tag setup. There is only the option to setup the fields one by one. Did anyone recently setup a Listener with the new UI and can tell me how to setup correctly?

Comment: Under the publish manager there is PREVIEW option, there you can debug all your events and see what didn't fire and why
P.S
I prefer to keep my code clean of any 3rd party scripts, just keep them in your GTM

Comment: But can I debug my event listener? I couldn't get any responds from it at all. I'm testing keypresses and allthough I'm smashing my keyboard it won't notice anything

Comment: @Raimonds I would love to not have to do this but my client wants to know if someone is typing anything in a input wich is activated by hitting the enter key at the end. Without any clicks GTM isn't able to listen to this events. Thats why I wanted to create my own listener.